# Cycles ignores smooth

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

No matter how much I smooth my mesh in the render it alway has this sharp edges in the cup
[image]

Comment: have you tried turning it "flat" and then "smooth" again? sometime it works :)

Comment: When you say smooth, do you mean setting smooth shading, using the smooth modifier or the subsurf modifier?

Comment: I model this in Maya and export it i just added with ctrl-1 or ctrl-2 the smooth. I also used from the tool bar the smoth and flat options but it keeps showing like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>1</kbd> adds a *Subdivision Surface* modifier with one subdivision, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>2</kbd> with two subdivisions and so on. However, adding the modifier this way only changes the number of subdivisions used in the viewport, and the number used for the render gets its default, which is **2**. Go to the *Modifiers* tab and change the *Render* value in the modifier to the same as or higher than the *View* value. The idea behind this is to get an idea what the subdivision does even in the viewport, without making it too computationally demanding until it's really needed, which is, of course, in the final render.

[image]

Comment: @EstefaníaDeLaVegaGarcía Glad I could help.